# SpringBoot Transactional Propagation REQUIRES_NEW doesn't create new Transaction

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, transactions, spring-transactions

I have the following scenario:

```
@Service
public class ServiceA {

  @Autowired private ServiceB serviceB;

  public void runA(){
    serviceB.runB()
  }
}

@Service
public class ServiceB {

  @Autowired private ServiceC serviceC;

  @Transactional
  public void runB(){
    serviceC.runC()

    ...rest of the logic
  }
}

@Service
public class ServiceC {

  @Autowired private TestRepository testRepository;

  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public boolean runC(){
    Optional<TestEntity> testEntityOptional = testRepository.findByKeyAndType("Key", "Type");
   if(testEntityOptional.isPresent()) {
     testEntityOptional.get().setActive(true);
     return true;
   }
   return false;
  }
}

@Transactional
public interface TestRepository
    extends JpaRepository<TestEntity, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<TestEntity> {

  @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
  @QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value = "5000")})
  Optional<TestEntity> findByKeyAndType(@NotNull String key, @NotNull String type);
}
```

I expect next flow:

1. `ServiceA.runA()` invokes `ServiceB.runB()`
2. `ServiceB.runB()` opens TRANSACTION_1 (or use transaction if it's opened before) as default propagation is `REQUIRED`
3. `ServiceB.runB()` invokes  `ServiceC.runC()`
4. `ServiceC.runC()` opens TRANSACTION_2 because propagation is `REQUIRED_NEW`
5. `ServiceC.runC()` invokes `TestRepository.findByKeyAndType()` to fetch testEntity by some criteria
6. `TestRepository.findByKeyAndType()` return record from DB which match the criteria and lock it for read/update
7. `ServiceB.runC()` process the record
8. `ServiceB.runC()` returns value and TRANSACTION_2 is committed and so lock released
9. `ServiceB.runB()` returns and TRANSACTION_1 is committed

But from my testing this is not the case. It seams that `ServiceC.runC()` do not create new transaction (TRANSACTION_2) even propagation `REQUIRED_NEW` is set (or it do not commit it at the return), and lock is released only when `ServiceB.runB()` returns (when TRANSACTION_1 is committed)

Do anyone see what I am doing wrong here? Is this normal behavior of SpringBoot?

Also the lock timeout doesn't work:
I am using Postgress v10 for DB where lock_timeout is set to "0".

So it looks like `@QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value = "5000")})` doesn't work as once record is locked, the other transaction which try to read the record hangs for a while until the record is unlocked

Comment: thank you for logging property. I just debug and 100% sure that new transaction is not opened

Answer (score 0):

Once I enabled `logging.level.org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager=DEBUG`, this is what I see. It includes suspension and resumption.

Is your transaction manager also `JpaTransactionManager`?

```
2020-06-30 01:11:53.239 DEBUG 47133 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [com.example.accessingdatajpa.BlogService.save]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2020-06-30 01:11:57.532 DEBUG 47133 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(1968179698<open>)] for JPA transaction
2020-06-30 01:11:57.538 DEBUG 47133 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@7f2542f]

2020-06-30 01:12:02.432 DEBUG 47133 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(1968179698<open>)] for JPA transaction
2020-06-30 01:12:04.032 DEBUG 47133 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Suspending current transaction, creating new transaction with name [com.example.accessingdatajpa.Service2.save]
2020-06-30 01:12:06.915 DEBUG 47133 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(2143659352<open>)] for JPA transaction
2020-06-30 01:12:06.916 DEBUG 47133 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@42fd8f2f]
2020-06-30 01:12:10.196 DEBUG 47133 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(2143659352<open>)] for JPA transaction
2020-06-30 01:12:11.489 DEBUG 47133 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Participating in existing transaction

2020-06-30 01:12:12.227 DEBUG 47133 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction commit
2020-06-30 01:12:13.082 DEBUG 47133 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(2143659352<open>)]
2020-06-30 01:12:13.109 DEBUG 47133 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(2143659352<open>)] after transaction
2020-06-30 01:12:13.110 DEBUG 47133 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Resuming suspended transaction after completion of inner transaction

2020-06-30 01:12:16.409 DEBUG 47133 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction commit
2020-06-30 01:12:17.541 DEBUG 47133 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1968179698<open>)]
2020-06-30 01:12:17.542 DEBUG 47133 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(1968179698<open>)] after transaction
```